# Is there a faster way to get Wikipedia API information than using continue?

Tags: python-requests, request, wikipedia-api

I'm requesting the viewcount for 50 articles and I'm using a loop to resend the request if the Wiki API returns a 'continue' json object. Is there a way I can speed this up, or a faster way to get the view count for the 50 articles?

[Here's an example call](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=pageviews&format=json&pvipcontinue&titles=Armor%20(Marvel%20Comics%20character)%7CCassandra%20Lang%7CCopperhead%20(Marvel%20Comics)%7CAlternative%20versions%20of%20Venom%7CAmphibion%7CChaste%20(Marvel%20Comics)%7CCenturius%7CAmadeus%20Cho%7CAgents%20of%20S.H.I.E.L.D.%7CClint%20Barton%20(Marvel%20Cinematic%20Universe)%7CCorsair%20(comics)%7CCarlos%20Pacheco%7CAnaconda%20(character)%7CBlade%20(film)%7CAnti-Venom%20(Marvel%20Comics)%7CBlack%20Swan%20(comics)%7CAvengers%20Forever%7CBadoon%7CAlternative%20versions%20of%20Spider-Man%7CCaptain%20Marvel%20(Mar-Vell)%7CChameleon%20(Marvel%20Comics)%7CAttuma%7CAtlantis%20Attacks%7CAlan%20Davis%7CBruce%20Banner%20(Marvel%20Cinematic%20Universe)%7CBig%20Man%20(comics)%7CArmor%20Wars%7CBrute%20(Reed%20Richards)%7CBrent%20Jackson%7CBig%20Hero%206%20(comics)%7CBeast%20(comics)%7CBetsy%20Ross%20(character)%7CAvengers%20Unplugged%7CCivil%20War:%20Young%20Avengers/Runaways%7CAgent%20Carter:%20S.H.I.E.L.D.%2050th%20Anniversary%7CCobalt%20Man%7CBlack%20Fox%20(Raul%20Chalmers)%7CAvengers%20Disassembled%7CBattlestar%20(character)%7CAl%20Milgrom%7CCaptain%20Marvel%20(Marvel%20Comics)%7CAchebe%20(character)%7CBloodaxe%20(character)%7CDaimon%20Hellstrom%7CByrrah%7CCaptain%20America:%20Reborn%7CAgents%20of%20Atlas%7CAir-Walker%7CBrothers%20Grimm%20(comics)%20left.child.title=%27Agents%20of%20S.H.I.E.L.D.%27)

Here's my code that loops until the continue object is gone

```
while 'continue' in json_object:
            json_object = _request_json(api)
```

here's the project repository if it helps:
https://github.com/averagephotographer/wiki-solver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could download the [pageview data dump](https://dumps.wikimedia.org/other/analytics/).